# Barcode Printing issues in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, barcode

I am trying to create Barcode on Cryetal reports 13. I am facing following problems.

1. When I set orientation to landscape (which is proper orientation), Printer prints in Portrait and vice versa.
2. Printer uses a few empty labels before and after the printed one.
3. The position of print on label is random, Sometime it prints on top, sometimes on bottom and so on.

Comment: Hi, 
1. What is the size of your barcode ( height and width ) ?
2. What is the paper size you selected when creating Crystal Report ?
3. What is the printer you are using to print ?

Comment: Barcode size= 1.7x1,3, Label Size (Paper size)= 1.7x1.3, printer TDS Tsp-255

Answer (score 0):

if you sure from label size in crystal report design 
then check paper size on printer option

Comment: IT'S A COMMENT.,.. to other post